# Add a new folder to each subfolder

Tags: windows

I have main a folder say `E:\donuts` and there are hundreds of folders inside it. e.g.

```
E:\donuts\yellow\
E:\donuts\green\
...
E:\donuts\blue\
```

I want to create a new folder in each subfolder simply using some DOS command. 
Something like this.

```
E:\donuts\yellow\big
E:\donuts\green\big
```

and so on. How can I achieve this?

Also, would to be possible move the content of each subfolder into the corresponding `big` folder? For instance all the files and folders in `E:\donuts\yellow\` should move to `E:\donuts\yellow\big` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so you'll want to try it out first

```
FOR /d %A IN (e:\donuts\*) DO mkdir "%A\big"
```

This should work to do the move as well:

```
FOR /d %A IN (e:\donuts\*) DO mkdir "%A\big" & mv "%A\*.*" "%A"
```

Comment: Wow @paul, the first one worked like a charm. I hope the second one will work too. Thanks a lot. I have been try various combos the whole evening but now I see my syntax was wrong.

Comment: Slight modification on the second command worked for me. It moved all the files sans folders. How can I change it to move the folders too?
FOR /d %A IN (e:\donuts\*) DO mkdir %A\big & move %A\*.* %A\big\

Comment: Oops yeah, well done.

Comment: Yeah @Paul thanks to you I'm almost there but the above command only moves files not folders. How can i achieve that?

Comment: You can't easily unfortunately, the move command doesn't accept wildcard directory names

Comment: I see. What about copy commmand it has this limitation too?

Comment: Not sure if `mv` is supported, `HELP` just defines `MOVE`

Comment: As far as I can see there is a /r missing, at least I am not able to create directories in subdirectories just with /d, i.e. for /r /d %%A in etc.