# Adding a sub folder to multiple directories where the name of the directories contains punctuation

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I would like to create the same sub-directory in each directory of a folder. I found the answer here:

[Add a new folder to each subfolder](https://superuser.com/questions/359392/add-a-new-folder-to-each-subfolder)

The command prompt was:

```
FOR /d %A IN (e:\donuts\*) DO mkdir "%A\big"
```

But perhaps because my director names contain spaces and commas, I end up with a bunch of directories based on the first word in each of the existing directories and a bunch of errors in the command prompt.

What variation can I use to allow for the fact that my directories have commas and spaces in the names?

Comment: Your command looks correct - you'll need to give examples of the errors and directories created.

Comment: Directories are named "LastName, FirstName Household"

I get errors such as:
A subdirectory or file name FirstName already exists.
Error occured while processing: FirstName
A subdirectory or file Household\Tax already exists
Error occured while processing Household\Tax

Tax is the name of the directory I am trying to create.

Comment: For the record, I did set up a directory with commas and spaces in the name, and the command in your original post works flawlessly. But all my W7 systems have been updated to W10, so so maybe it's a bug in the W7 version of `cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell!

Run this PowerShell command when you're in the folder whose subfolders should have the new folders added to them:

```
dir | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | % {md ($_.FullName + '\New folder')}
```

This lists the entries in the current folder (with `dir`, an alias for `Get-ChildItem`), then filters them (`?`) down to the ones that are folders. For each folder found, a new folder is created (`md`) with the full path as the path of the found subfolder plus a constant string, in this case `\New folder`, but you can set that to whatever you want, including things that have spaces and commas.

In PowerShell 3 and higher, it can be condensed to this:

```
dir -Directory | % {md ($_.FullName + '\New folder')}
```

Here, `dir` takes an optional `-Directory` flag to only get folders.

To call this command from a batch script:

```
powershell -Command "dir | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | % {md ($_.FullName + '\New folder')}"
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the following error:

Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Direct
ory'.
At line:1 char:15
+ dir -Directory <<<<  | % {md ($_.FullName + '\Tax')}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @Anthony My mistake, I forgot that the `-Directory` switch isn't supported in PowerShell 2, the version that comes with Windows 7. I've updated my answer with an option that will work for you.

Comment: Nice, I was staring at the page trying to find out how to mark the answer good.  You read my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing "" quotes on either end of the directory filename. So it would be:

```
FOR /d %A IN ("e:\donuts\*") DO mkdir "%A\big"
```